# How to get form’s link in Cognito Forms

Tags: cognito-forms

How do I get the form’s link after publishing it? I’m getting only the embedding code, and no share links. I need the share link — how can I get it?

Answer (score -1):

I am a developer for [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com).

To help prevent malicious phishing attacks, our system automatically blocks public links for users in some regions. We do this to help keep users personal information safe. We will be happy to review your form and verify that your form is not violating our terms of service. We see that you have already submitted a support ticket for this issue, and we will work with you through that ticket to get this resolved as soon as possible.

Comment: What regions are blocked? Otherwise this answer is like saying the answer is behind a support ticket